# String.match.length returning array. Expected an integer value.

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to write a function that counts the matches of a letter of the alphabet to letters in a string. I then store the count, per letter, into an associative array.

My problem is that `string.match(regExpression) || [].length` is returning an array. My expectation is it would return an integer value matching the length of the match. I know that the string.prototype.match() method returns an array, but my understanding (based on the formal description of the method) is that Sting.length returns a number.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    function countLetters(string) {
    //create array with letters of alphabet
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
    var counts = []; 

  for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    var regExpression = new RegExp(alphabet[i], "g"); 
    counts[alphabet[i]] = string.match(regExpression) || [].length
  }
  return counts; 
}
```

Comment: If `string.match` is successful then it will return an array...

Comment: Well ignore the `array` and pick the `value` out of it that you need.

Comment: I thought that .length was the part that would ignore the array and give me the value I was looking for. @john how do you suggest I do it?

Comment: I am on it. You want the count of matches for each letter, right?

Answer (score 2):

I realize my mistake. The line `string.match(regExpression) || [].length` was behaving unexpectedly since I was missing parenthesis around the match method and logical operator before invoking the `length` method. As is I was returning the array OR the length of an empty array.

I also changed `counts` to an object.

Here's the fixed function:

```
function countLetters(string) {
    //declare array with letters of alphabet
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
    //declare object which will store our counts
    var counts = {}; 

  //iterate through alphabet array, find matches, and assign count of matches to counts object
  for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    var regExpression = new RegExp(alphabet[i], "g"); 
    counts[alphabet[i]] = (string.match(regExpression) || []).length
  }
  return counts; 
}
```

Comment: Up voted. I'm actually surprised that nobody caught the use of an array in place of an object. Yet, often times it's the simple bugs that you spend hours trying to solve. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong but you are expecting the wrong value, in this case when string.match is right it will return an array which is the right behavior.

> This method is used to retrieve the matches when matching a string against a regular expression, and those matched returned in an array

Comment: Thank you, Ahmad, and I was expecting an array back from the match. However, I thought that the `length` method would then give me the specific value to store into the associative array `counts`. That's the part that is not happening and I don't understand why.